# Как выйти за границу .container?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть заголовок с линией под ним, которая начинается слева от контейнера, а заканчивается в правом краю экрана:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
h2{
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.line{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю, чтобы было адаптивнее стоит добавить .line{
right: 0
}
Только при этом, .line растянулся на всю ширину(